# Is there a tool for cleaning JSON files from comments and trailing commas?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, formatting

I wonder if there is an online tool or VS Code extension that easily removes all comments and trailing commas, because removing them manually every time isn't practical.

[image: Exemple in VS Code]

Comment: JQ perhaps? https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: you can do a simple search for a comma followed by whitespace and `}` or `]` and replace by the whitespace and the closing bracket

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I'm not sure how I can achieve that using JQ.

Comment: @rioV8 It's only working when there's no comment between the comma and the bracket.

Comment: then remove the `//xcfder` comments first

Comment: @rioV8 We're talking about thousands of comments, I'm not gonna remove all of them manually.

Comment: you can do that with a simple regex search replace

Comment: @rioV8 I don't know how to do that

Comment: with a similar regex you use to remove the trailing comma, or write a NodeJS, Python script that cleans the JSON.

Comment: @rioV8 If I was able to do that, I wouldn't be here from the start..

Comment: learning regular expressions is a very useful skill and that often allows you to solve problems without going to SO and waiting till somebody solves it for you